# Making jquery function to work across multiple forms. (Making Jquery DRY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've created a simple js function called from a button-onclick to do something straight forward, submit the data 'selected' and open a new tab. This was a single use case, worked fine for this one case. But NOW, as I'm scripting out more and more widgets within my feature, (tabs presenting different tools, within the same DOM). I'm finding way harder to keep the DRY.

I want to set up the forms to have same general inputs, get which form it is by the form id, serialize and let the controller deal with the rest. Knowing the form id will allow some exceptions to some forms, if needed. Each attempt has me banging my head on my desk. 
Why are no forms being executed?
And if I get one form working, why isn't the other? [Similar code sample with '.change']
How do I get this ideal code to work across all the forms

OldCode:
**JS**

```
function doaction(){
    alert("I work perfectly");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id='form_w'>
   <input type='hidden' name="action" />
   <input type='text' name="term"></input>
   <input type='button' onclick="doaction()"/>
</form>
```

Ideal Code:

**jQuery**

```
//$('form.results').submit(function(e){ //DIDNT WORK
$('.rbutton').click(function(e){        // NOT WORKING EITHER
    alert("This alert doesnt exist");
    var form_id = e.target.id;
    // gather data
    // submit data via ajax
    // update the dom by adding another tab/widget.
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id='form_tab_id1' class="results">
   <input type='hidden' name="A_action" />
   <input type='text' name="term"></input>
   <input type='button' class='rbutton'/>
</form>
<form id='form_tab_id2' class="results">
   <input type='hidden' name="A_action" />
   <input type='text' name="term"></input>
   <input type='button' class='rbutton'/>
</form>
<form id='form_tab_id3' class="results">
   <input type='hidden' name="B_action" />
   <input type='text' name="term"></input>
   <input type='button' class='rbutton'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you adding `.rbutton` to the form?

Comment: check your formatting. you have stray quote symbols in the tags

Comment: Why are you using click instead of submit?

Comment: Sorry guys, i scripted out the rbutton in code to see if that did the trick before I pasted it. Its added in to each button. @Chris

Comment: Either or Really, as long as it kicks off ajax and doesn't refresh the page. I think I read a posts that is the common action of '.submit', a page redirect. @KevinB

Comment: the primary issue of using click instead of submit is it doesn't intercept the submit event, therefore if the form was "submitted" in a way that didn't include clicking that button, it would bypass your click event. You can of course avoid that issue by removing `<form>` too.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a user posted a solution. I am greatful he did. It pointed me in the right direction. [It was removed for whatever Reason that may be. But thanks George.]

His Solution was the following.

**JQuery**

```
$('.rbutton').click(function(){
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
}
```

After juggling with so many variations, my code was drifting into an unstable code set. I honestly didn't know how to go about this; JQuery is prolly my sworn enemy. But knowing that the code George posted should be working, and wasn't, it kind of pointed me into other factors that I didn't consider. [I didn't take into consideration the code was being executed before the tabs with the '*.rbutton*' element were being populated.]

The Solution that helped me make this a more DRY principle was the following JQuery;

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click','.rbutton',function(){
     var form = $(this).closest('form');
     // Actions that are needed to be performed
}
```

Reason why this helps, or at least with my code, it binds this function to any element with the class '*.rbutton*' including new instances. As i mentioned above,these buttons were created after the jQuery was being executed; So nothing was being binded essentially. The following will do the binding to newly created elements, as if tho there was an active listener doing the additional binding over the document even after the code had been executed.